# WPF/MVVM Abstract Common Methods

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

SO Community, please bear with me as I am a newbie and I'm still learning(slowly). I have tried to implement absolutely every potential solution on the net with no success. I think I've completely confused myself with DependencyMethods, DependencyProperties, RelayCommands, ICommand, BaseViewModels, etc........

Here's my scenario... I have a MainWindow(MainWindow) with a Frame containing a UserControl(SampleUC). The MainWindow and UserControl DataContexts are pointed to their respective ViewModels(MainWindowVM, SampleUCVM). MainWindowVM and SampleUCVM are children of a Base ViewModel(BASEVM) which uses INotifyPropertyChanged through an ObservableCollection helper class. There is a Combobox inside SampleUC that holds the Facilities ObservableCollection constructed in SampleUCVM with method "fillFacility" and stores the SelectedFacilityNum when selected in the Combobox with the "GetFacilityNum()" method.

I would like to pull out the methods "fillFacility" and "GetFacilityNum" from the SampleUCVM and place them either in the BASEVM or a separate class where they can be accessed and used by other ViewModels. They will be used repeatedly throughout my project. Would someone be able to explain to me how to do this? Thank you for all your help and patience!

**SampleUC.xaml**

```
    <Grid>
    <Label Content="Facility" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Height="27"/>
    <ComboBox Name="cboFacilities" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="119,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
              DisplayMemberPath="FacilityName"
              SelectedValuePath="FacilityName"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Facilities}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFacility, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              />
</Grid>
```

**SampleUCVM**

```
public class SampleUCVM : BASEVM
{

    #region MySQL Connection

    const string dbConnectionString = @"datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog='optest1a1';username=root;password=";

    #endregion

    private ObservableCollection<Facilities> _facilitiesList;
    private string _selectedFacility;
    private int _selectedFacilityNum;

    public ObservableCollection<Facilities> Facilities
    {
        get { return _facilitiesList; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _facilitiesList, value, () => Facilities);
        }
    }

    public string SelectedFacility
    {
        get { return _selectedFacility; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedFacility, value, () => SelectedFacility);
            if (_selectedFacility != null)
            {
                GetFacilityNum();
            }
        }
    }

    public int SelectedFacilityNum
    {
        get { return _selectedFacilityNum; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedFacilityNum, value, () => SelectedFacilityNum); }
    }

    public SampleUCVM()
    {
        Facilities = new ObservableCollection<Facilities>();
        fillFacilities();
    }

    private void fillFacilities()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
        {
            Facilities = new ObservableCollection<Facilities>();
            con.Open();
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM facilities";
            MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
            MySqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 1;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string FacilityName = dr.GetString(1);
                Facilities facilityname = new Facilities(count, FacilityName);
                Facilities.Add(facilityname);
                count++;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void GetFacilityNum()
    {
        if (SelectedFacility != null)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                string Query = "SELECT Facility_ID_Num FROM facilities WHERE Facility_Name='" + SelectedFacility + "' ";
                MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
                MySqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
                int count = 1;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    int FacilityNum = dr.GetInt32(0);
                    SelectedFacilityNum = FacilityNum;
                    count++;
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BASEVM**

```
    public class BASEVM : ObservableObject
{
    public BASEVM()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad, having many possible answers. That said: IMHO the VM should be very simple, especially as the program itself gets more complicated. It's not clear how it would be useful for your "facilities"-related code to be shared among view models, but based on what you've posted here, it seems more likely that code all belongs in a different class entirely. Then any view model class that needs that functionality can _have_ an instance of that different class, rather than _be_ an instance of a class that has that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into implementing a data access layer for this kind of thing. For example:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    public ObservableCollection<Facilities> GetFacilities()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Facilities> facilities = new ObservableCollection<Facilities>();

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM facilities";
            MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
            MySqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 1;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string FacilityName = dr.GetString(1);
                facilities facilityname = new Facilities(count, FacilityName);
                facilities.Add(facilityname);
                count++;
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        return facilities;
    }
}
```

You could then include an instance of this on your ViewModel classes (or on some ViewModel base class).

With regards to your `GetFacilityNum()` method, this could also go into the `DataAccess` class, but personally I think a better solution would be to include the `Facility_ID_Num` as a property of your `Facilities` class, if possible. You would then just need to amend the `GetFacilities()` method to pull that in as well, but then within the application you'd always be able to access this without any database calls as it would be part of your `Facilities` Model.

Answer (score 0):

You're making things much complex than they really are.
`ObservableCollection<T>` is sufficient to notify WPF controls on changes has happend to it so far; just make sure it is properly bound from XAML.

As such

`public ObservableCollection<Facilities> Facilities
    {
        get { return _facilitiesList; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _facilitiesList, value, () => Facilities);
        }
    }`

is redundant and should be simplified to

`public ObservableCollection<Facilities> Facilities
    {
        get;
    }`

and initialized only once - from the constructor.

As far as you want it to be at the base view model, just move the code there. Then inherit your child models from your base model and thus child would get such a property as part of themselves.

And forget about `SetValue(...)` unless you register your own, custom `DependencyProperty` which is necessary only for advanced scenarios.

Those are start points.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with `Peter Duniho` your question is too broad, and there is no definite answer to it, but I would like to highlight some points to you.
What is the purpose of your `BASEVM` And why it inherits from `ObservableObject`

> Class that wraps an object, so that other classes can notify for
>   Change events. **Typically, this class is set as a Dependency Property**
>   **on DependencyObjects, and allows other classes to observe any changes**
>   **in the Value**.

If you want a basic notification change functionality you could do something like this.

```
public class ViewModelBase:INotifyPropertyChanged{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);

        return true;
    }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs)
After that, you inherit from this `ViewModelBase` class. And when any property changed, you fire the `PropertyChanged` event like this:

```
public int SelectedFacilityNum
{
    get { return _selectedFacilityNum; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _selectedFacilityNum,value); }
}
```

> I would like to pull out the methods "fillFacility" and
>   "GetFacilityNum" from the SampleUCVM and place them either in the
>   BASEVM or a separate class where they can be accessed and used by
>   other ViewModels

`fillFacility` method, as shown in your code is dealing with the `database`. As far as I know, in `MVVM` pattern, `ViewModels` are meant to meditate between the `View` and the `Model`

> The view model acts as an intermediary between the view and the model,
>   and is responsible for handling the view logic. Typically, the view
>   model interacts with the model by invoking methods in the model
>   classes. The view model then provides data from the model in a form
>   that the view can easily use. The view model retrieves data from the
>   model and then makes the data available to the view, and may reformat
>   the data in some way that makes it simpler for the view to handle.

So, I suggest to separate the `Data Access` logic from your view model to a separate `Data Access` layer. For example, you can use the `Repository` pattern and create a `FacilityRepository`. And then you can provide this repository to the `ViewModels` require this functionality. And if you want to be more strict you can create `IFacilityRepository` interface, make the `FacilityRepository` implement it, and then you inject this interface to any `ViewModel` requires this functionality.